# Default title tooltip in IE10 is misplaced

Tags: tooltip, internet-explorer-10

I am facing an issue of tooltip on IE10. IE10's default tooltip that shows the text of title attribute of anchor element is getting misplaced by 20px to 40px above its intended placement. Do we have any resolution for this issue or something documented over Microsoft's site about this bug.

Comment: What do you mean "intended placement"?

Comment: In IE9, tooltip can be seen just below the anchor element when user hovers it but same thing doesn't happen in IE10.

Comment: That may be true, but there is no *intended placement*; the position of the tooltip is not a defined standard. It may be the case that IE10 places the tooltip on top for touch-purposes. With it below the link, your finger would be blocking its view.

Comment: I think tooltips doesn't appear on touch screens rather they appear only on mouseover. If I am wrong than come up with some example where screen touch shows tooltip.

Comment: Tooltips also appear on touch screens in Internet Explorer 10. As [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534683(v=vs.85).aspx) says, Internet Explorer "renders the title as a ToolTip when the user hovers a mouse **or finger** over objects."

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip is not misplaced, it's positioned in such a way that it won't be obstructed by a finger or stylus touching the object. If the tooltip were placed below the object being hovered, it would be difficult to read as you'd have to look beneath your finger for the displayed information.

As tablets and touch-enabled devices become more ubiquitous, we can expect to see these types of changes become more necessary for a better user experience.

Comment: But is there any way to change tooltip's placement when a user is browsing in IE10 over a touch-disabled device and rather using mouse to do so.

Comment: @AnkurGupta No, the position of the tooltip is up to the device. If you want more control, I would encourage you to go with a third-party solution.